# Open graph URL does not contain language

Tags: sxa, link-manager, socialshare

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8, I want to embed the language in the `og:url` meta tag, I've checked the configuration of the `LinkManager`, `languageEmbedding` is set to true, but still it's not reflected in `og:url`

Comment: Have you checked if it's the same in clean Sitecore instance with SXA installed? If yes, I guess the best option would be to create a Sitecore Support ticket

Comment: I checked, it's the same, but after more investigation I found out the og:url value reads from Target Hostname, which is a shared field and can't assign a language to it, I don't know if this behavior can be overridden or there an OOB solution